# PcSpim syntax error on pseudo instructions

Tags: assembly, syntax, syntax-error, mips

I keep getting syntax error if i use instructions like li or la. If i try a code without these instructions it works fine, but i need to use them. I tried different versions and i keep getting the same error (I have allowed pseudo instructions). I need to use it for a university project but i can't check if the code i wrote is ok since i can't run the code. 
Am i missing something? I don't know how to make it work properly, i'm new to assembly and pcspim, so i may be overlooking something stupid.

Update: If i use PcSpim i can't get any code to work. I tried using QtSpim and MARS to test my code and they both read the code (although it's still not correct). The point is i have to use PcSpim for my project, so i need to get it running.

Comment: This is the error message i get: spim: (parser) syntax error on line n of file x and it always point to the first line with li or la instruction.

Comment: Right. Well that's a half example. What's the offending code? And not just one line either

Comment: Ok, here you have an example (the most simple code i could get):   `.data
str: .asciiz "the answer = "
.text
    li $v0, 4       # $system call code for print_str
    la $a0, str     # $address of string to print
    syscall         # print the string

    li $v0, 1       # $system call code for print_int
    li $a0, 5       # $integer to print
    syscall         # print it`          but i get the same error with any code.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is with your setup. I installed PCSpim 9.1.9 on a Windows 7 64-bit machine, kept the default settings, and tried the code you pasted in your comment (only adding a `main` label and an `exit` syscall); it works just fine.

Comment: I have PCSpim 9.1.9 and Windows 7 64bit too, and still i can't get it to work in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try ONLY selecting the two following Options in the Settings menu under Execution:
(1) Mapped I/O
(2) Allow pseudo instructions

uncheck all others.

This helped me removing this error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the label main.

Comment: Yes, i just noticed the label main got cut in that code, but that's not the problem, i get the same error even with main, and with EVERY code with those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Select the "Settings" menu and verify that "Permit extended (pseudo) instructions and formats" is checked.

Comment: In the settings menu i have an "Allow pseudo instructions" option, and it's already checked.

Comment: Are the line endings consistent in your source file? Try running `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` on the source file.